# Puppet file link doesn't create target under Windows

Tags: puppet

```
file {'VaultUsersLink':
      path => "C:/VaultWorkspace/VaultUsers.lnk",
      require => File['VaultWorkspace'],
      ensure => link,
      target => "C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/facter/facts.d/inventorusers.txt",
      owner => 'SYSTEM',
      group => 'Users',
      mode => 0776,
      }
```

Seems like it should make a shortcut, and it does make a 0 byte file named VaultUsers.lnk, but doesn't fill in the target. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link is not a Windows shortcut.  A link is symbolic link.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link.  Does the file `inventorusers.txt` also have zero bytes?

> link will make sure the file is a symlink, and requires that you also set the target attribute. Symlinks are supported on all Posix systems and **on Windows Vista / 2008 and higher. On Windows, managing symlinks requires puppet agent’s user account to have the “Create Symbolic Links” privilege;** this can be configured in the “User Rights Assignment” section in the Windows policy editor. By default, puppet agent runs as the Administrator account, which does have this privilege.

Comment: Ummm, did you read your link?:[...]a symbolic link (also symlink or soft link) is a special type of file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution.[...]Today they are supported by the POSIX operating-system standard, [...] and also Windows operating systems such as Windows Vista, Windows 7 and to some degree in Windows 2000 and Windows XP in the form of Shortcut files.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of what that page says, the important part is the **'to some degree'**.  Shortcuts are not symbolic links, they only act like them **to some degree**.  They are stored differently on the filesystem.  Their similaries doesn't really doesn't matter, because the 'link' type within puppet refers to [NTFS windows symbolic links only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Windows_symbolic_link).  The windows file provider does not create shortcuts files (.lnk files).